# How can I store the form values in CSV using django instead of using Database?

Tags: django, python-3.x, csv

How can I store values of Name,Email (entered details from form values) Fields store in **CSV** file using python django.

Comment: What's the context here? Writing a CSV file is trivial thanks to [the `csv` module in Python's standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv). But if you're trying to use a CSV as a database backend (i.e., to look up, modify, and save data using Django's ORM) I think you're out of luck. (As an aside, a single CSV file maps reasonably well to a single database table; to represent a whole database you would probably need several CSV files.)

Answer (score 0):

Say your Django form is called `form`, and you've already validated it. Then it has an attribute `cleaned_data` which is a dict. We can convert this dict to CSV format via csv.DictWriter:

```
import csv
with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=form.cleaned_data.keys())
    writer.writerow(form.cleaned_data)
```

Comment: Can you give me a Example or Demo? because i got a error message like this,'module' object has no attribute 'DictWriter'

Comment: 'module' object has no attribute 'DictWriter'.This error I can't able to fix